# The performance issue with FlatList in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a TabNavigator with two screens, each representing a stack navigator. On the first screen, all recipes are displayed in a FlatList, and I fetch the data from the Redux store. The second screen also contains a FlatList, with data dependent on the first screen and fetched from the store. I modify the state of each individual item in the FlatList on the first screen. There are no issues upon the initial app load, but after navigating to the second screen and returning, the process of adding and removing items from favorites starts to lag. Moreover, the more items are added, the more the function slows down. Here is the link to the repository: https://github.com/AlexeyKaluzhniy/recipesApp

I attempted to use React.memo and FlashList instead of FlatList. While FlashList does improve performance, there are still noticeable delays. It feels like more items are being added than there actually are, and the list constantly re-renders the component. I don't know what the issue is; I really need help.

Comment: I've cloned your repo, hardcoded the data (100 items) and ran the app but didn't see any problems. I only see this in console: `VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc.`

Comment: Try to remove redux hooks from the `CardRecipe` component and make it only accept props.

Comment: @Alisher nothing changes after removing redux hooks.
if I remove the flat list from the favorite screen, and, for example, leave the output only item.name then the problem will disappear, it is probably in the flatlist, but I don't know what exactly is the cause

Comment: How many items in the list do you have? I've tested it with 100 items and it works well. Try to clear cache with `expo start -c` and reinstall the dependencies.

Comment: The fact is that there are few elements, only 30.
I recorded the screen to make it more clear what the problem is, before entering the favorites tab, adding and removing from favorites occurs without delay, and after switching, with each new element there is an increasing delay when clicking on the heart.
https://youtube.com/shorts/RHZYwlwE-sQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the Favorites tab and then navigate back to the Recipes tab, the Favorites tab remains mounted. See [Navigation lifecycle docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle).

So when you press on a heart button, the Favorites tab re-renders in the background because it is subscribed to the part of the store that is changing.

You will need to control the Favorites tab based on its focused or blurred state.

#### #1. Render nothing when the tab is blurred

```
export default function Favorite({ navigation }: FavoriteProps) {
    const favoritesData = useSelector(selectFavoriteData);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    if (!isFocused) return null;

    // return ...
}
```

This is the easiest way but the scroll state will be lost when switching between tabs.

#### #2. Manually manage store subscription

```
export default function Favorite({ navigation }: FavoriteProps) {
    const store = useStore<RootState>();
    const [favoriteIds, setFavoriteIds] = useState<string[]>();
    const favoritesData = store.getState().data.recipes
        .filter(recipe => favoriteIds.includes(recipe.id));

    useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
        const storeListener = () => setFavoriteIds(store.getState().favorite.recipeIds);
        storeListener();
        return store.subscribe(storeListener);
    }, [store]));

    // return ...
}
```